# ASP.net MVC Core/Signal R Core - Server returned handshake error: An unexpected error occurred during connection handshake

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-signalr

I'm currently trying to set up Signal R Core in an existing asp.net MVC Core application. On page load, the following message is logged in the console:

`Information: WebSocket connected to ws://localhost:53108/Hubs/PaperworkAuditHub?id=njA7swSt57ASK2cTU-hmRQ.`

However, below that I get the three following javascript errors:

```
Uncaught Error: Server returned handshake error: An unexpected error occurred during connection handshake.
at HubConnection.processHandshakeResponse (signalr.js:2406)
at HubConnection.processIncomingData (signalr.js:2350)
at WebSocketTransport.HubConnection.connection.onreceive (signalr.js:1922)
at WebSocket.webSocket.onmessage (signalr.js:4709)

[2019-10-10T14:14:57.431Z] Error: Connection disconnected with error 'Error: Server returned handshake error: An unexpected error occurred during connection handshake.'.

Uncaught (in promise) Error: Server returned handshake error: An unexpected error occurred during connection handshake.
at HubConnection.processHandshakeResponse (signalr.js:2406)
at HubConnection.processIncomingData (signalr.js:2350)
at WebSocketTransport.HubConnection.connection.onreceive (signalr.js:1922)
at WebSocket.webSocket.onmessage (signalr.js:4709)
```

The project is targeting .NET Core 2.2, and using the latest Signalr Core packages from nuget as well as the latest signalr.js file.

Below are the `ConfigureServices()` and `Configure()` methods from `Startup.cs`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });


        services.AddSignalR();
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver());
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver()).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseWebSockets();
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseCookiePolicy();
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapHub<PaperworkAuditHub>("/Hubs/PaperworkAuditHub");
            routes.MapHub<RouteScheduleHub>("/Hubs/RouteScheduleHub");
            routes.MapHub<EfficiencyZoneHub>("/Hubs/EfficiencyZoneHub");
        });
        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Account}/{action=Login}");
        });
    }
```

Finally, here is the relevant code snippet from the .cshtml view.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("@Url.Content("~/Hubs/PaperworkAuditHub")")
    .build();
```

I've tried several solutions (moving `UseSignalR()` above `UseMvc()` in `Startup.cs`, completely redoing the SignalR setup), but so far am still getting the same error.

Comment: You can try to increase HandshakeTimeout property, like this `services.AddSignalR(options=> {options.HandshakeTimeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue;});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We discovered that the issue was actually extra SignalR packages that had been added. After completely stripping out SignalR and redoing the setup (making sure that ONLY the packages specified were installed) everything worked correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to send this right after the establishing of the connection:

```
wss://localhost:port/hub-name
```

```
{
  "protocol": "json",
  "version": 1
}
```

Note that at the end of the message there's `0x1E` character